# Find key for two values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, compare, key-value

I need to find if two values have the same key.

Dictionary looks like this, where the values are lists:

```
d1 = {"a": ["1", "2"], "c": ["5", "8", "76"], "b": ["3", "9"], "o": ["47"]}
```

So I want to compare for example `(5, 8)`: `True`

Comment: ... a list of `["5","8","76"]` is different from `["5","8"]` - and iterating over values of a dictionary is not what dictionaries are good for ...

Comment: if i want to find the key for value 8. Is it posible ?

Comment: *"two values have the same key."*: You mean, find the dict item where **two** values e.g `5` and `8 `, within the same dict value, here `"c": ["5", "8", "76"]`? Read [Dictionary view objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects)

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for *subsets* and *supersets*; your two values must together be a subset of a dictionary value.

Convert your tuple to a set, then use [`set.issubset()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset) together with [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) to find if there is a value in your dictionary that contains both values:

```
test_set = {"5", "8"}
any(test_set.issubset(v) for v in d1.values())
```

Note that because the objects in your lists are strings, you must use strings in the test set too!

Using sets here is as efficient as Python can make it given your data structures; internally, `test_set.issubset(v)` will convert the list to a set, then test each element in `test_set` against that temporary set (each test taking constant time), making this a O(N) linear time operation. If you have to do this many times over, and performance is an issue, consider making the values in `d1` sets to start with.

As a function that accepts integers too:

```
def all_same_key(d, *t):
    test_set = set(map(str, t))
    return any(test_set.issubset(v) for v in d.values())
```

which you can then call with `all_same_key(d1, 5, 8)`.

Demo:

```
>>> all_same_key(d1, 5, 8)
True
>>> all_same_key(d1, 5, 1)
False
>>> all_same_key(d1, 47)
True
```

If you must find the keys, then use a list comprehension over `dict.items()`, and filter on values where `test_set` is a subset:

```
[key for key, value in d1.items() if test_set.issubset(value)]
```

Comment: superior solution :)

Comment: Kudos for the simple and useful solution!